# Module build failed: Error: Could not resolve module 'bootstrap-sass' which must be installed when bootstrap version is configured to v3

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-loader

Upon building an angular project i met with below error:

```
ERROR in ./~/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.loader.js!./~/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js
Module build failed: Error: Could not resolve module 'bootstrap-sass' which must be installed when bootstrap version is configured to v3.
You must install 'bootstrap' for bootstrap v4 or 'bootstrap-sass' for bootstrap v3.
You can also specify the location manually by specifying 'bootstrapPath' in bootstrap-loader's query string.
See https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader/blob/master/README.md#usage.
    at Object.module.exports.pitch (/home/dev/Work/zzz/node_modules/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.loader.js:147:11)
 @ ./~/bootstrap-loader/loader.js 2:17-61
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3007 ./src/vendor.browser.ts
```

In package.json i have
in dependencies:

```
"bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
```

and in devDependencies:

```
"bootstrap-loader": "2.0.0",
```

Also in bootsrap loader: bootstrapVersion is 4 still somehow it is picking up version 3.

How can i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if there is ".bootstraprc" file in your root directory as described in https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-loader.

Comment: Thanks that file was missing, now it is working. Many Thanks.